# Lipschitz condition on the region

Tags: calculus

Try that :

$\displaystyle f \ (x,y) = x^2 |y|$

satisfies a Lipschitz condition on the region $\displaystyle |x| ≤ 1 \ , |y| ≤ 1,$ but that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} $ does not exist at many points in that rectangle.

if $|x\leq 1,\quad |y|\leq 1$:

$|f(x,y)-f(x',y')|=|x^2|y|-x'^2|y'||=|x^2|y|-x^2 |y'|+x^2|y'|-x'^2|y'||\leq |x^2|||y|-|y'||+|x^2-x'^2| |y'|\leq \\
\qquad \leq ||y|-|y'||+|x-x'||x+x'|\leq d((x,y),(x',y'))+2d((x ,y),(x',y'))\leq 3(d(x,y),d(x',y'))$

and therefore it is from Liptchiz.

It now checks that the partial $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ of $x^2|y|$ does not exist at points $(x_0, 0)$ with $x_0\neq 0.$

taking into account that at a point $(x_0,0)$ we have by definition that:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,0)=\displaystyle\lim_{y \to 0}{}\dfrac{f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,0)} {y}=\displaystyle\lim_{y \to 0}{}\dfrac{x_0|y|}{y}$

the limit on the right and on the left do not coincide and therefore the limit does not exist and neither does the corresponding partial derivative.

Did I perform the demonstration correctly or am I missing something to add? I hope your help, I want to know if it is OK in this way. If you have another way to demonstrate it, I would also like you to explain it please.